# google chrome seems to stutter when I scroll in my Django blogging app

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-chrome

Google chrome seems to stutter when I scroll up or down in my Django app, but safari or firefox scroll just fine. I thought it was because I was using cdn for bootstrap, jquery. Just was wonderig if this was a common problem and if there was a common fix thank in ad vance. 
Heres my base.html

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
<!--doctype html -->
<html>

    <head>
        <title> {% block head_title %} try django 1.9 {% endblock head_title %}</title>

        <style>
            {% block style %}
            {% endblock style %}
        </style>

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "posts/css/base.css" %}'/>
    </head>

    <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">HiSPANIC HEiGHTS</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">


          <form method="GET" action="{% url 'posts:search' %}"  class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="input-group">{% csrf_token %}
              <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" class="form-control"
              style="width: 350px">




              <ul id="search-results">

              </ul>

            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span style="font-size:1.4em" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> </button>
            </span>
            </div>
          </form>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="{% url 'posts:list'  %}">Home</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="#">Sewp</a></li>-->
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'posts:create' %}">Create</a></li>
            {% endif %}

          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
</nav>



        {% include "includes/messages_display.html" %}

        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 66px">
            {% block jumbotron %}{% endblock jumbotron %}



            {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        </div>



        <footer>



        </footer>


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript put in includes-->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
                crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>

        <script src="{% static 'posts/js/jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.js' %}"></script>

        <script>
            $("nav.navbar-fixed-top").autoHidingNavbar();
        </script>


    </body>

</html>
```

like I said,firefox, and safari work but chrome seems to stutter. Any help is welcome

Comment: Open the page with DevTools, check js errors

Comment: @AviahLaor the error I see is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: try to fix that resource